# How to fix or change randomly marked json snippet?

Tags: xetex, minted, code-snippets, json

So my problem is that my json snippets are marked red, but I don't want to mark them red. How my JSON looks like:

```
[
{obj1}
{obj2}
{obj3}
]
```

And my snippet looks like:

```
[
{obj1}

...

]
```

And that ... is outlined by red mark (it looks like indicating that there is some errors).

My preamble for json snippet looks like:

```
\newminted{json}{breaklines,frame=bottomline,rulecolor=\color{snipgray},framerule=0.6pt}
```

My snip looks:

```
\begin{snip}\captionof{listing}{Bla bla bla}\label{lst:a3}
\begin{jsoncode}
[
{"bla":1,
"bla2":"4"
}
...
]
\end{jsoncode}
\end{snip}
```

Answer (score 2):

When `minted` finds a syntax error (such as `...`) it draws an `fcolorbox`. You can redefine this command within `minted` environments to prevent drawing of the box, as per https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/69#issuecomment-81612590.

For future reference, please provide a complete minimal working example (MWE) instead of a few fragments, as shown below. I have simplified it a bit (that is the 'minimal' part of MWE). Also: this is not related to `xetex`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}        % for \AtBeginEnvironment
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{snipgray}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\newminted{json}{frame=bottomline,rulecolor=\color{snipgray},framerule=0.6pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{jsoncode}{%
  \renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{jsoncode}
    [
    {"bla":1,
    "bla2":"4"
    }
    ...
    ]
    \end{jsoncode}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]